# Variable returning unexpected 0 in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The variable 'bubbleBankCapacity' is expected to return as 500 and be compared to the 'regularBubbleCount' variable in the comparison below, but instead returns as 0 which effectively makes the condition false given that the regularBubbleCount is greater than 0. Why is this returning a 0 when it has been set to initialize as 500?

## AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(void)timerCalled
{
    NSLog(@"Timer Called");
    if ([RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier > 0) {
        if ([RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount < [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleBankCapacity) {
            NSLog(@"bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier);
            [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount += [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryTickValue;
            NSLog(@"bubbleFactoryTickValue: %i", [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryTickValue);
            [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Capacity Reached! Capacity: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleBankCapacity);
        }

    } NSLog(@"Regular Bubble Count: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount);
}
```

## RWGameData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RWGameData : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (assign, nonatomic) long regularBubbleCount;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long premiumBubbleCount;

@property (assign, nonatomic) long megaBubbleUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubblersUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleBankUpgradeTier;

@property (assign, nonatomic) int megaBubblePopValue;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int bubbleFactoryTickValue;

@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleBankCapacity;

+(instancetype)sharedGameData;
-(void)reset;
-(void)save;

@end
```

## RWGameData.m

```
#import "RWGameData.h"

@implementation RWGameData

static NSString* const SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey = @"regularBubbleCount";
static NSString* const SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey = @"premiumBubbleCount";

static NSString* const SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey = @"megaBubbleUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey = @"bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey = @"bubblersUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey = @"mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey = @"bubbleBankUpgradeTier";

static NSString* const SSGameDataMegaBubblePopValueKey = @"megaBubblePopValueKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleFactoryTickValueKey = @"bubbleFactoryTickValueKey";

static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleBankCapacityKey = @"bubbleBankCapacityKey";

+ (instancetype)sharedGameData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)reset {
    self.regularBubbleCount = 0;
    self.premiumBubbleCount = 0;

    self.megaBubbleUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubblersUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubbleBankUpgradeTier = 0;

    self.megaBubblePopValue = 1;
    self.bubbleFactoryTickValue = 1;

    self.bubbleBankCapacity = 500;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.regularBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.premiumBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.megaBubbleUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubblersUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleBankUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.megaBubblePopValue forKey: SSGameDataMegaBubblePopValueKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleFactoryTickValue forKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryTickValueKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleBankCapacity forKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankCapacityKey];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _regularBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
        _premiumBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey];

        _megaBubbleUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubblersUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey];
        _mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubbleBankUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey];

        _megaBubblePopValue = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMegaBubblePopValueKey];
        _bubbleFactoryTickValue = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryTickValueKey];

        _bubbleBankCapacity = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankCapacityKey];
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSString*)filePath
{
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance
{
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [RWGameData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        RWGameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return gameData;
    }

    return [[RWGameData alloc] init];
}

-(void)save
{
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[RWGameData filePath] atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you call `reset` on your shared game data instance? Ie why do you think it should be 500?

Comment: Oh, duh. Thank you @Paulw11. So the real question here is where would be the best place to initialize these variables? They have already been declared in the header but I need to set values for them when they are referenced for the first time (aka the program is run for the first time).

Comment: I would suggest that you call reset in your `dispatch_once` block

Comment: The better place to put it would be to explicitly define an `init` method and have reset be called there. If you look at how he structured the code, the `dispatch_once` will call `loadInstance` which will either load persisted data or create a new instance. Note that obviously `initWithCoder` is calling init, but those values will get over-written later by the decoded values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I went ahead and declared a boolean property to RWGameData and tasked the reset method to set it to true when the reset method had been called. Then I went ahead and adjusted - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if (![RWGameData sharedGameData].dataIsInitialized) {
        [[RWGameData sharedGameData] reset];
    }

    NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

Thank you to everyone who offered a solution to this problem. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `bubbleBankCapacity` variable in `AppDelegate.m` inside your method.